# Flask JSON Append does not work

Tags: javascript, json, flask

I am trying to append json into JSON's structure, [] but I face a very weird situation.
I tested this code using different database procedure code and it worked. However, when I use my code, it doesn't work although all the remaining things are same and I do get the result from database.

For simplicity, I removed unnecessary parts.

Script code for both of them are

```
<script>
$(function(){
          $.ajax({
              url: '/getAllWishes' or '/getAllMovies',
        type: 'GET',
              success:function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              },
              error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
              }
          });
    })
</script>
```

Working code is

```
@app.route('/getAllWishes')
def getAllWishes():
    try:
            print('test')
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('sp_GetAllWishes',(3,))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            print('result')
            print(result)

            wishes_dict = []
            for wish in result:
                wish_dict = {
                        'Id': wish[0],
                        'Title': wish[1],
                        'Description': wish[2],
                        'FilePath': wish[3],
                        'Like':wish[4],
                        'HasLiked':wish[5]
                        # 'Id': '1',
                        # 'Title': '1',
                        # 'Description': '1',
                        # 'FilePath': '1',
                        # 'Like':'1',
                        # 'HasLiked':'1'
                        }
                wishes_dict.append(wish_dict)   
                # print(wishes_dict)
            return json.dumps(wishes_dict)
            #return json.dumps('[]')

    except Exception as e:
        return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
```

and its printed result is

```
((4, u'Test', u'test', u'static/Uploads/667ca948-7ab0-4045-9b53-9646ece56336.jpg
', 1, 1), (5, u'wow', u'wow', u'static/Uploads/ddcf2c6a-7c03-4a97-850f-5f60fe246
f90.jpg', 0, 0), (6, u'ww', u'ww', u'static/Uploads/15b361bd-2d4d-4bb9-84d2-5ca9
1b15a0e6.jpg', 0, 0), (7, u'aa', u'aa', u'static/Uploads/36e2b946-5969-4587-84ed
-d8c1aab6dd6a.jpg', 0, 0), (8, u'ss', u'ss', u'static/Uploads/a35114be-8143-4113
-aff3-5de1fd89a464.jpg', 0, 0), (9, u'dd', u'dd', u'static/Uploads/a675a843-c158
-4cde-bb0e-86b44665dd4f.jpg', 0, 0), (10, u'ff', u'ff', u'static/Uploads/111cb65
0-0469-45cf-98d4-b0d035ad616c.jpg', 0, 0), (11, u'aaa', u'aaa', None, None, 0))
```

and its result from console in browser is

```
[{"Description": "test", "FilePath": "static/Uploads/667ca948-7ab0-4045-9b53-9646ece56336.jpg", "HasLiked": 1, "Id": 4, "Like": 1, "Title": "Test"}, {"Description": "wow", "FilePath": "static/Uploads/ddcf2c6a-7c03-4a97-850f-5f60fe246f90.jpg", "HasLiked": 0, "Id": 5, "Like": 0, "Title": "wow"}, {"Description": "ww", "FilePath": "static/Uploads/15b361bd-2d4d-4bb9-84d2-5ca91b15a0e6.jpg", "HasLiked": 0, "Id": 6, "Like": 0, "Title": "ww"}, {"Description": "aa", "FilePath": "static/Uploads/36e2b946-5969-4587-84ed-d8c1aab6dd6a.jpg", "HasLiked": 0, "Id": 7, "Like": 0, "Title": "aa"}, {"Description": "ss", "FilePath": "static/Uploads/a35114be-8143-4113-aff3-5de1fd89a464.jpg", "HasLiked": 0, "Id": 8, "Like": 0, "Title": "ss"}, {"Description": "dd", "FilePath": "static/Uploads/a675a843-c158-4cde-bb0e-86b44665dd4f.jpg", "HasLiked": 0, "Id": 9, "Like": 0, "Title": "dd"}, {"Description": "ff", "FilePath": "static/Uploads/111cb650-0469-45cf-98d4-b0d035ad616c.jpg", "HasLiked": 0, "Id": 10, "Like": 0, "Title": "ff"}, {"Description": "aaa", "FilePath": null, "HasLiked": 0, "Id": 11, "Like": null, "Title": "aaa"}]
```

and not working code is

```
@app.route('/getAllMovies')
def getAllMovies():
  print('getAllMovies-------------------------')
  try:
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('sp_GetAllMovies')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print('result')
    print(result)

    movies_dict = []
    print(movies_dict)

    for movie in result:
     movies_dict = {
      # 'title': movie[0],
      # 'mtype': movie[1],
      # 'rating': movie[2],
      # 'myear': movie[3],
      # 'imagepath': movie[4]
      'title': '1',
      'mtype': '1',
      'rating': '1',
      'myear': '1',
      'imagepath': '1'
     }
     print('movies_dict')
     print(movies_dict)
     movies_dict.append(movies_dict)
     print('movies_dict after append')
     print(movies_dict)
    return json.dumps(movies_dict)
    #return json.dumps('[]')
  except Exception as e:
   return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))
```

and its printed result is

```
((4, u'Test', u'test', u'static/Uploads/667ca948-7ab0-4045-9b53-9646ece56336.jpg
', 1, 1), (5, u'wow', u'wow', u'static/Uploads/ddcf2c6a-7c03-4a97-850f-5f60fe246
f90.jpg', 0, 0), (6, u'ww', u'ww', u'static/Uploads/15b361bd-2d4d-4bb9-84d2-5ca9
1b15a0e6.jpg', 0, 0), (7, u'aa', u'aa', u'static/Uploads/36e2b946-5969-4587-84ed
-d8c1aab6dd6a.jpg', 0, 0), (8, u'ss', u'ss', u'static/Uploads/a35114be-8143-4113
-aff3-5de1fd89a464.jpg', 0, 0), (9, u'dd', u'dd', u'static/Uploads/a675a843-c158
-4cde-bb0e-86b44665dd4f.jpg', 0, 0), (10, u'ff', u'ff', u'static/Uploads/111cb65
0-0469-45cf-98d4-b0d035ad616c.jpg', 0, 0), (11, u'aaa', u'aaa', None, None, 0))
```

and it gets the error when committing "movies_dict.append(movies_dict)" line.

I don't really understand why it is not working. I have tested this part for more than a day already. Please help.. Thanks.

Comment: @Momin Hi. I think my code is minimal. I'm trying to read data from MySQL, input data into dictionary, and get the result from javascript using ajax.. I appreciate your comment though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're appending movies_dict with it self, I guess you want to append it with movie, as movie is your loop var.

you can use something like

```
movies_dict.update(movie)
```

OR

```
import itertools
movie_dict = dict(itertools.chain(movies_dict, result))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but unfortunately, it doesn't work.. After applying either of your answers, it updates nothing.. Do you have any idea??

Comment: I think it seems to be related to database related problem. When executing json related function, it does not work. I can provide you any related information. I really really appreciate your help..
@app.route('/getAllMovies')
def getAllMovies():
  try:
    conn = mysql.connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.callproc('sp_GetAllMovies')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    movies_dict = []
    movie_dict = dict(itertools.chain(movies_dict, result))
    return json.dumps(movies_dict)
  except Exception as e:
   return render_template('error.html',error = str(e))

Comment: It's very easy, if you are getting nothing start logging each statement you are writing, in new code I don't understand why you're using movie_dist, as you're doing nothing with that var, if you're not doing any process directly return result. if you're getting any error please log that.

Comment: Thank you so much again. I wanted to input the result JSON object into "[]" so that the javascript side code can get it. The working code append the DB result in {"a1":"d1", ..., "an":"dn"}, {...} formats and it goes into [], which is moviedict after using append function. But my code somehow doesn't work when executing append function. If I directly return the result in json.dump function, its format is likt [[], ..., []], which I cannot parse from javascript side. All remaining things are same but I'm facing this error and I don't understand why it is not..... Thank you so much..